# Error 324 empty response on Application hosted by AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

I am getting this error on my amazon EC2 server. This doesn't happen on a specific page on my website. I don't think it is Chrome browser bug either because when I open safari I don't get the error, I get a white page. Not sure what is happening or why. Basically, I am looking for the root causes for this server error. Any ideas would be much appreciated. If you need me to provide any specific info, let me know.

Come to think of it, this error started happening when we upgraded to mongo php driver 1.2.7. Thoughts?

Comment: This is probably apache segmentation fault. Check out apache error log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trouble-shoot with `curl` from the commandline. For example, http://aws.amazon.com/

```
$ curl -i http://aws.amazon.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 May 2012 19:55:14 GMT
Server: Server
x-amz-id-1: 0C8YK9MYJMCCSE8R09E5
x-amz-id-2: zx0HtU9Ub39tobXNBiMRLuE2mvnhQo4Kh1fyj0MdJcg=
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Tue, 08 May 2012 19:55:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-cookie: aws-session-id-time=2082758401l; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 00:00:01 GMT
Set-cookie: aws-session-id=000-0000000-0000000; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 00:00:01 GMT
Vary: User-Agent
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
...
```

The `-i` includes headers. You should see the actual status code and then correlate with your `access_log` and `error_log`. :)

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Except a CURL shows me the HTML just fine, but it's not loading up in a browser. What in the world could be causing something like this :( Everything was fine until last night.

Comment: Cookies? A session? I'm not sure what else since your question is pretty vague. Maybe use the debugger (in Chrome: CMD+Option+J) and see what the browser says?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to document my answer to this absolutely time-sucker of a problem. For me a `curl` showed the right HTML, but my browser wasn't.

I promptly disabled `Session Stickiness` from the AWS Console for my LoadBalancer and it works just fine now.

@Till's `curl` advice is brilliant :)

Edit: How do you manage this problem in the future when you need session stickiness? I have no idea. But there should be answers on this out there!

Comment: Thanks, happy to help. Does "session stickyness" with ELBs refer to redirecting the user to the same server always? If so, I avoid such things and use a central session store (memcache with MySQL for persistence) and redirect the user to the server with the least load.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else sees this question and @Till's answer didn't help.  I wanted to point out the Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer has a hard coded 60 second timeout.  There is no way to disable it.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=33427&start=0&tstart=50

You need to add a "heartbeat" your page, to return data through the HTTP connection.  The ELB monitors the activity and will keep your session alive.

This may be overboard for some applications, it totally removes any php buffering that was started and flushes the data to the webserver.  In addition to this, GZIP needs to be disabled at the web server (apache, or other).

The script returns a fairly large amount of data, about 64,000 single spaces.  Consecutive single spaces are ignored by the browser, so it is usually pretty easy to configure your page to use this functions without any display concerns.

You also do not need to call this function very often.  You have 60 seconds, I usually try and get mine to run every 10 to 15 seconds, but since it does sleep for one second, don't call it too often or you will see a significant slow down in your page.

Here's the function:

```
function ELB_HeartBeat(){
echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

ob_implicit_flush(true);
while ( @ob_end_flush() );

@flush();
@ob_flush();

sleep(1); }
```

Comment: Just a quick update that at least in 2021, it is now configurable: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html#config-idle-timeout-console