# How can I upload a file to amazon S3 with Codeigniter/PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to my Amazon S3 bucket. My friend had this working on our site in the past but a year later its busted and I can't figure out what's wrong. We are using the [S3 PHP library](http://www.neurofuzzy.net/2006/08/26/amazon-s3-php-class-update/) developed by [Geoff gaudreault](https://twitter.com/neurofuzzy).

This library looks pretty straightforward to me, really it looks like there is one key function: `putObject()`.

Unfortunately, I'm not even getting out of the gate. I'm getting the following error message:
`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.`

Here's my codeigniter PHP for my upload form `action`:

```
    function s3(){

    $config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/temp/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024000';
    $config['max_height']  = '768000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        print_r($error);
        echo 'failure';
    }
    else
    {
       $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
        $fn = $data['file_name'];
        $type = substr($fn, strrpos($fn, '.') + 1);

    $this->load->library('s3');
    $temp_file_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/temp/" . $data['file_name'];
    $contents = read_file($temp_file_path); // will this blow up or timeout for large files?! 
    $newFileName = uniqid().".".substr($temp_file_path, strrpos($temp_file_path, '.') + 1);
     $contentPath = "mysite.com/Images"; 

    $this->s3->putObject($newFileName, $contents, $contentPath, 'private', $type);
    echo 'success';
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 324 empty response on Application hosted by AWS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861404/error-324-empty-response-on-application-hosted-by-aws)

Comment: hi Colin, I'm not sure where how to access my S3 server from the command line. My EC2 server /etc/apache2/error.log makes no mention of this Error 324. thoughts?

Comment: First thing to point out is that you can use the functionality within CodeIgniter for the Filename/Paths etc. First, you can use the `encrypt_name` option instead of generating your `$newFileName` manually. Secondly, `$data['full_path']` contains the full path to the uploaded file, `$data['file_ext']` contains the file extension and finally, instead of using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` you should be ok simply using `$config['upload_path'] = './temp';` The upload script takes the path relative to the index.php in your root. HTH

Comment: awesome, thanks Gavin! let me take a few minutes to digest what you just said, i'm still a novice....

Comment: hi Gavin, i think the error is in my usage of the AWS S3.php library. I'm able to do uploads using CI's File uploading Class to my server no problem. Its only when I throw in the `$this->load->library('s3');` and the subsequent `putObject()` call to that library that things blow up.

Comment: Typical huh ;) Glad to hear you've got everything sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched to a [different S3 PHP library](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/), which is also referred to as S3.php,  that is part of this really nice Netuts tutorial source code.

Just plugging in my AWS keys and bucket name into the demo's page.php file, I was able to upload to my bucket in like 2 minutes. So this tutorial is super easy. Very exciting!

Comment: this is used for core php not for codeigniter framework

Comment: this question (and this answer) is too old, AWS has a new sdk in its repository https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php And is easily installable as a library in codeigniter through composer or copying the sdk.

Answer (score 1):

in codeigniter

Here link to [upload](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2017/06/how-to-image-and-file-upload-using-aws.html) and [delete](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2017/06/how-to-file-delete-in-s3-bucket-in-aws.html) image in s3 bucket

```
<?php

function profile_upload()
{
    //print_r($_FILES);
    if ($this->session->userdata('user_login')) {

        $file = $_FILES['agent_profile_file']['tmp_name'];

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $typefile    = explode(".", $_FILES["agent_profile_file"]["name"]);
            $extension   = end($typefile);

            if (!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)) {
                //not image
                $data['message'] = "images";
            } else {
                $userid = $this->session->userdata['user_login']['userid'];

                $full_path = "agent_image/" . $userid . "/profileImg/";

                /*if(!is_dir($full_path)){
                mkdir($full_path, 0777, true);
                }*/
                $path = $_FILES['agent_profile_file']['tmp_name'];

                $image_name = $full_path . preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\._]+/", "-", strtolower(uniqid() . $_FILES['agent_profile_file']['name']));
                //move_uploaded_file($path,$image_name);

                $data['message'] = "sucess";

                $s3_bucket = s3_bucket_upload($path, $image_name);

                if ($s3_bucket['message'] == "sucess") {
                    $data['imagename'] = $s3_bucket['imagepath'];
                    $data['imagepath'] = $s3_bucket['imagename'];
                }

                //print_r($imagesizedata);
                //image
                //use $imagesizedata to get extra info
            }
        } else {
            //not file
            $data['message'] = "images";
        }

    } else {
        $data['message'] = "login";
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    //$file_name2 = preg_replace("/ /", "-", $file_name);
}

// Helper file add code
// image compress code
function compress($source, $destination, $quality)
{
    ob_start();
    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }

    $filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "beyondbroker");

    imagejpeg($image, $filename, $quality);

    //ob_get_contents();
    $imagedata = ob_end_clean();
    return $filename;
}

// type for if image then it will reduce size
// site for it in web of mobile because mobile webservice image will in base 64
// $tempth will file temp path
// $image_path will file where to save path

function s3_bucket_upload($temppath, $image_path, $type = "image", $site = "web")
{
    $bucket = "bucket-name";

    $data = array();

    $data['message'] = "false";

    // For website only
    if ($site == "web") {
        if ($type == "image") {
            $file_Path = compress($temppath, $image_path, 90);
        } else {
            $file_Path = $temppath;
        }
    }

    try {
        $s3Client = new S3Client([
            'version'     => 'latest',
            'region'      => 'us-west-2',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => 'aws-key',
                'secret' => 'aws-secretkey',
            ],
        ]);

        // For website only
        if ($site == "web") {

            $result = $s3Client->putObject([
                'Bucket'     => $bucket,
                'Key'        => $image_path,
                'SourceFile' => $file_Path,
                //'body'=> $file_Path,
                'ACL'        => 'public-read',
                //'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
            ]);

            $data['message']   = "sucess";
            $data['imagename'] = $image_path;
            $data['imagepath'] = $result['ObjectURL'];
        } else {
            // $tmp = base64_decode($base64);
            $upload            = $s3Client->upload($bucket, $image_path, $temppath, 'public-read');
            $data['message']   = "sucess";
            $data['imagepath'] = $upload->get('ObjectURL');
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $data['message'] = "false";
        // echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }

    return $data;
}
```